# While sending text message my application shows message "application example has stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: android, sms

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {        
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Msgactivity.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message, pi, null);
}
```

In the above code while executing `sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message, pi, null);` statement my application shows "application example has stopped unexpectedly" message.

I added user permission to manifest file

What might the cause for the message?

LogCat output is--

```
09-05 15:39:11.758: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(403): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<

09-05 15:39:11.758: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(403): CheckJNI is ON

09-05 15:39:12.648: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(403): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm

09-05 15:39:12.678: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(403): Shutting down VM

09-05 15:39:12.698: DEBUG/dalvikvm(403): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms

09-05 15:39:12.708: DEBUG/dalvikvm(403): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

09-05 15:39:12.739: INFO/AndroidRuntime(403): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

09-05 15:39:13.328: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(413): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<

09-05 15:39:13.328: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(413): CheckJNI is ON

09-05 15:39:14.188: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(413): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am

09-05 15:39:14.228: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=task.list/.DolistActivity } from pid 413

09-05 15:39:14.308: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(413): Shutting down VM

09-05 15:39:14.318: DEBUG/dalvikvm(413): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms

09-05 15:39:14.328: DEBUG/dalvikvm(413): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

09-05 15:39:14.428: INFO/AndroidRuntime(413): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

09-05 15:39:15.138: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed task.list/.DolistActivity: +877ms

09-05 15:39:20.599: DEBUG/dalvikvm(138): GC_EXPLICIT freed 57K, 49% free 3059K/5959K, external 1625K/2102K, paused 68ms

09-05 15:39:21.879: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { cmp=task.list/.Msgactivity } from pid 374

09-05 15:39:22.349: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed task.list/.Msgactivity: +457ms

09-05 15:39:27.319: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(120): No keyboard for id 0

09-05 15:39:27.319: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(120): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

09-05 15:39:31.968: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(374): Shutting down VM

09-05 15:39:31.968: WARN/dalvikvm(374): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:77)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at task.list.Msgactivity.sendSMS(Msgactivity.java:51)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at task.list.Msgactivity.access$0(Msgactivity.java:46)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at task.list.Msgactivity$1.onClick(Msgactivity.java:38)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-05 15:39:31.998: WARN/ActivityManager(70):   Force finishing activity task.list/.Msgactivity

09-05 15:39:32.528: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406a9190 task.list/.Msgactivity}

09-05 15:39:32.698: INFO/dalvikvm(70): Jit: resizing JitTable from 1024 to 2048

09-05 15:39:34.609: INFO/Process(374): Sending signal. PID: 374 SIG: 9

09-05 15:39:34.629: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Process task.list (pid 374) has died.

09-05 15:39:34.649: ERROR/InputDispatcher(70): channel '406de700 task.list/task.list.DolistActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error 
occurred.  events=0x8

09-05 15:39:34.649: ERROR/InputDispatcher(70): channel '406de700 task.list/task.list.DolistActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

09-05 15:39:34.678: INFO/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{406de700 task.list/task.list.DolistActivity paused=false}

09-05 15:39:34.729: INFO/WindowManager(70): WIN DEATH: Window{40713818 task.list/task.list.Msgactivity paused=false}

09-05 15:39:34.799: ERROR/InputDispatcher(70): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=162, events=0x8

09-05 15:39:35.089: WARN/InputManagerService(70): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 374 uid 10043
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste your logcat output for the exception. To add logcat go to windows -> show view -> Logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-05 15:39:31.988: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(374):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress

That's the reason. "Invalid destinationAddress"